# java explain the String str.trim().split();

Tags: java

Can someone explain how this works? Which one works first and how can I use more than one method in one shot?

```java
String[] temp = str.trim().split(" ");
```

Comment: Left to right, chaining works on the return value.

Comment: In the beginning, there was `str`. Upon `str`, the method `trim()` was called, producing a value of type `String`. Upon this value, `split` was called, producing a value of type `String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Java always evaluating from left to right.

So, first you have a `String` (`str`). `str.trim()` returns a String that is trimmed. On that trimmed string that you now have, you can run another function, even when you didn't save it into a variable.

And then you run the `split()` method which returns an array of `String`s.

Comment: "always works from left to right"? Not **always**:  `2 + 3 * 10` or `a = b = 3` || left to right is valid for the operands of **one** operation (one operator) or argument lists

Comment: @user16320675 it's **always** left to right. Consider `int a = 1; System.out.println(a + a++ * 2);` If `a++ * 2` were evaluated first, then the `a` at the start would be 2, so the result would be `2 + 1 * 2 = 4`. But `a++ * 2` is **not** evaluated first. It's evaluated left to right. `a` is 1 at all times except just after its 2nd appearance. So the expression evaluates to 3. Don't confuse operator precedence with order of evaluation.

Comment: @k314159 it is always evaluated left to write, but I guess the whole problem here is that I said "work" and not evaluated. Even when all calculations is evaluated left to write, we still can be waiting for results from the right side evaluation before continuing with the left side evaluation. That's why `2+2*2` is 6, as we start from left, but depends on the result from the right to arrive before continuing. And I edited my answer again, to be more clear as you said

Comment: @k314159 OK, so lets do it left to right, shall we? `System.out` - we got `out`; next is `println`, wait, we need the argument(s); it is on the right but we did not work the left side yet... always left-to-right did not work here (lets ignore that one) ||  Argument is `a + a++ * 2`, simple: `a + a++` -> `1 + 1` is `2`   and `a` incremented to `2`; next `2 * 2` (the result of `1+1` times `2`) really? NO, always left-to-right does not work here either ||   Seems like "evaluation order" != "work order"

Comment: @user16320675 very interesting, I need time to get my head around such a complicated expression

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what do you have on your variable str.

Trim will remove all blanck spaces in the start and in the end of your string. Example: if you have a string like this `"  string   "` the result will be `"string"`.

Split will return an array of strings. example: if you have a string like this `"this is my string"` and you apply a split(" ") it will return to you something like this: `["this", "is", "my", "String"]`.

Good coding

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that we have this string : " Hello world "
as you see we have sapce before Hello and space after world so trim will eliminate those spaces and split(' ') will make all word sparated by space in table like this ["Hello","world"]